# Setting text view from another activivty using intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I am trying to get a text view to update after a user has typed in a string from another result.  When using this method below I get what appears to be the edit text's code address.  Something like "android.widget.Edittext(b142f388 etc." regardless of what the user types in on the other activity.  What am I missing here?

String collected from user:

```
private void enterClicked() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");

    //Save user provided input from the EditText field
    String result = mEditText.toString();

    //Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
    Intent i = new Intent(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, ActivityLoaderActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("RESULT_STRING", result);

    //Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

    //Finish the Activity
    finish();

}
```

Activity Result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");

    // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
    // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.

    if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE){           
        String userData = data.getStringExtra("RESULT_STRING");
        mUserTextView.setText(userData);
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: Use  `String result = mEditText.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `getText()` method to get text from editText:

Try using this code: `String result = mEditText.getText().toString();`

```
private void enterClicked() {

Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");

//Save user provided input from the EditText field
String result = mEditText.getText().toString();

//Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
Intent i = new Intent(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, ActivityLoaderActivity.class);
i.putExtra("RESULT_STRING", result);

//Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

//Finish the Activity
finish();

}
```

Instead :

```
private void enterClicked() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");

    //Save user provided input from the EditText field
    String result = mEditText.toString();

    //Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
    Intent i = new Intent(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, ActivityLoaderActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("RESULT_STRING", result);

    //Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

    //Finish the Activity
    finish();

}
```

Comment: hind sight 20/20.  Makes sense why it wasn't returning the string correctly now.  Thanks a pant load :)

Comment: `getText().toString()`? What kind of object does `getText` return? Surely it could not be `String`?

Comment: As `EditText` class extends from `TextView` class so `getText()` method is dervied from `TextView` class that returns: `returns the text the TextView is displaying`. It's return type is `Editable` interface. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText())

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = mEditText.getText().toString();
```

First apply this and check result